# Image not being inserted into phpmyadmin database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using an input field of FILE type in order to insert image into my database and then view te image in front end.

This is the code I used in my pho file to insert the data:

```
function insert_product(){
    try{
        global $conn;
        //prepare statement 
        $statement = $conn->prepare("insert into products (product_name, product_brand, product_category, product_image, product_description, product_price, product_keywords) values (:product_name, :product_brand, :product_category, :product_image, :product_description, :product_price, :product_keywords)");
        //bind parametes
        $statement ->bindParam(':product_name', $product_name);         
        $statement ->bindParam(':product_brand', $product_brand);
        $statement ->bindParam(':product_category', $product_category);
        $statement ->bindParam(':product_name', $product_name);
        $statement ->bindParam(':product_price', $product_price);
        $statement ->bindParam(':product_description', $product_description);
        $statement ->bindParam(':product_keywords', $product_keywords);

        // executing the statement
        $product_name = $_POST['product_name'];
        $product_brand = $_POST['product_brand'];
        $product_category = $_POST['product_category'];
        $product_price = $_POST['product_price'];
        $product_description = $_POST['product_description'];
        $product_keywords = $_POST['product_keywords'];
        //getting the image from the field
        $product_image = $_FILES['product_image']['name'];
        $product_image_tmp = $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'];
        move_uploaded_file($product_image_tmp,"product_images/$product_image");
        $statement->execute();
        header('Location: index.php');
    }
    catch(PDOException $e){
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

When I try to insert the data I see this error:

[image]

I checked my parameters and don't quite understand what exactly is wrong.

How can I insert the image into my database and view it afterwards ?

Comment: You're binding `:product_name` twice, and `:product_image` not at all.

Comment: Also, you should call `bindParam()` **after** filling the variables you're using.

Comment: @rickdenhaan I hope you do not mind explaining your second comment so I know what am doing.

Comment: The code works now and I appreciate the support though.

Comment: At the point where you're binding the variables to the parameters, the variables have not been defined yet. `bindParam()` happens to bind the variables by reference so it doesn't matter that they get their value afterwards, but *nearly all* other PHP functions will give you an "undefined variable" warning for it. It's bad practice and an easy cause for headaches in future code maintenance.

Comment: @rickdenhaan Understood and thank you. Since am learning php I decide to  create a CRUD application using PDO. So I hope you have nice reference to help as well.